# any RAD tool for java app development?

Tags: java, rad

is there some RAD tool for creating java apps with event driven flow ? basically like visual basic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Java RAD web framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360963/best-java-rad-web-framework)

Comment: I suggest you first try searching for the answer. The 'related' questions sidebar has some good related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you define "RAD". The NetBeans IDE provides a way to easily drag-and-drop GUI components and create functions that will be invoked on the various events of those components.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CUBA Platform](https://www.cuba-platform.com/) - an open source framework which comes along with the CUBA Studio - its RAD tool. It covers most of common things out of the box:

- Enterprise (three tier) architecture from database to UI
- CRUD screens auto-scaffolding
- Visual model creation and screen designer
- Tool for legacy app migration
- Framework contains generic functionality for security, audit, scheduled tasks, data recovery, REST and other standard features of any enterprise application
- Reporting, BPM, charts and maps, full-text-search add-ons can be added in one click